# scala: How to safely accept functions returning [unspecified generic type parameter] --> Nothing?

Tags: scala, orientdb

I'm dealing with a 3rd party library (orientDB) that has a very large number of APIs of the form:

```
  trait MyTrait {
    def method[RET](): RET
  }
```

and many cases its sensible to call an instance of MyTrait *without* specifying the RET parameter.

For example: I might call document.save(db). Here I've called save[T=undef], and scala decides the result is of type Nothing.
In many cases this is not a big deal.

However consider something like this:

```
class DatabaseConnection

trait Saveable {
  def save[RET](db:DatabaseConnection): RET
}

class Document extends Saveable {
  // Let's assume only RET=Document is valid
  def save[RET](db:DatabaseConnection) = this.asInstanceOf[RET]
}


def wrap[T](func: (DatabaseConnection) => T): T = {
  val db = new DatabaseConnection
  try {
    func(db)
  } finally {
    // Close the database connection. Omitted
  }
}


def f(db:DatabaseConnection) : Unit = new Document().save(db)

f( new DatabaseConnection() )  // OK

wrap{ db =>
  new Document().save(db)  // FAIL. Document cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing
}
```

The first call succeeded because the Nothing result is never used: f ignores the result and returns unit.
The second call fails because new Document().save(db) promises a Nothing type (at least, that's what scala decided). The resulting failure is a little saddening since the wrapper is generic and seems like it *should* be able to accept functions that return *anything*, including Nothing.

I've found many posts that explain similar issues (generics + can't cast to Nothing), but none that explain how to deal with it without requiring the caller of wrap to provide the type parameter. It even fails when the type bounds have constraints that provide it must be an Object/Any.

Is it possible to modify wrap so that it works for any function taking a DatabaseConnection, even those returning Nothing? I don't want the caller to have to fully specify the type parameters because: i) is not necessary, ii) is very burdensome, iii) is not safe - since the caller will likely forgot.

For example, instead of specifying T, can I say I want a function who's return type is "DontCare" or "NothingOrAny"?  Constraining T=Nothing didn't help because the function actually returns a Document. It seems wrap should ask for functions returning T=Nothing OR Any.

UPDATE:

Here's a similar failing example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.{OResultSet, OSQLSynchQuery}

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument

def toODocumentValue(node:JsonNode):Any = 
node match {
  case e: NullNode => null
  case e: TextNode => e.asText()
  case e: BooleanNode => e.asBoolean()
  case e: DoubleNode => e.asDouble()
  case e: IntNode => e.asInt()
  case e: LongNode => e.asLong()
  case e: ArrayNode => e.elements().asScala.map(toODocumentValue(_)).toList.asJava
  case e: ObjectNode =>
    val doc = new ODocument
    e.fields().asScala.foreach(field => doc.field(field.getKey, toODocumentValue(field.getValue)))
    doc
}

  val JSON_PERSON_RECORD_LIST =
    """
[
      {
        "gender": {"name": "Male"},
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "account": {"checking": 10, "savings": 1234}
      },
      {
        "gender": {"name": "Male"},
        "firstName": "Dan",
        "lastName": "Dare",
        "account": {"checking": 10, "savings": 1234}
      }
]
    """

val db: ODatabaseDocumentTx = val db: ODatabaseDocumentTx = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("memory:jsondb")
db.create()


// Jackson mapper
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)


// Read a JSON of format [{obj1},{obj2},...]
// and save objects into DB
val node = mapper.readTree(JSON_PERSON_RECORD_LIST)

// Fails because db.save: Nothing
// Even though the return type is not used, scala checks its type
// at runtime.
node.elements().asScala.foreach{ node => db.save( toODocumentValue(node).asInstanceOf[ODocument] ) }
```

Caller is required to write:

```
// Added ORecord type parameter
node.elements().asScala.foreach{ node => db.save[ORecord](
   toODocumentValue(node).asInstanceOf[ODocument] ) }
```

Using scala with the ODB Java API sucks pretty hard because this style of generics is prolific in orientdb and the error is not caught until runtime. It really need its own scala API

Comment: Can you point to the APIs you are trying to use?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure it will help much (I'm more interested in the generic problem, than these APIs).

The specific case that tripped me up was:

 db.command(new OCommandSQL(queryString)).execute()

where db:ODatabaseDocumentTx

Comment: ... which is declared here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/command/OCommandRequest.java

Comment: Have updated the question with an example from orient DB

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to have more restrictive type for your `save` method. From it's name I assume that its purpose is to save only members of concrete subclasses of the trait `Saveable`.

So it makes sense to define `save` like this:

```
trait Saveable {
  def save(db:DatabaseConnection): this.type
}

class Document extends Saveable {
  def save(db:DatabaseConnection) = this
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it not possible since this portion is provided by a 3rd party API.

Comment: The allowed objects don't subclass Saveable, but I think there is a constraint the object subclass Any.